# How to center this div in a section?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Question Background:**

I'm using Bootstrap to create a page for a web app.

**The Issue:**

I have two `Sections` within the layout. I want the information `divs` within the `Sections` to be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Currently I cannot get the divs to center.

I have tried applying the following to the divs within the two sections, but there is no difference to the layout.

```
.centerSectionDivs{
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a code pen of my layout:

http://codepen.io/daveharris/pen/rxvLby

This shows the issues. Any help getting the information in the section perfectly centered would be much appreciated.

Comment: they are centered horizontally tho?

Comment: i didn't get what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use flex:

```
#section1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/xZzRav/

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your html is a class being used called .centerSectionDivs.

so nothing is going to change because it doesn't exist.

so this:

```
    .centerSectionDivs{
      margin:0 auto;
    }
```

isnt needed.

You might want to look into the other classes or id's to find out which one correlates to what